# How to list the running processes in C?

Tags: c, windows

I want to write a console-based process manager. In the first step I think I should have a list of running proceses. I'm using Windows.

Comment: So do you need to know how to do this on the Windows or Mac platform? They're different beasts.

Comment: my project is a Windows-based, but I want to know them both!

Comment: You are asking two completely different questions. It's not fair to ask both at the same time. Pick one, sort that out, and then come back for the other.

Comment: OK,let me know how to do it on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at [this example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682623%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). [This](https://www.google.ro/search?client=opera&rls=en&q=win32%20enum%20processes&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest) might also help.

Comment: You might also want to read some books about the WIN32 platform. I recommend the book [Programming Windows](http://www.charlespetzold.com/pw5/) by Charles Petzold.

Comment: I appreciate that this is years old, but link-only answers were discouraged even in 2012.  Pointing someone to the documentation or suggesting a Google search term is worthy only of a comment perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [CreateToolhelp32Snapshot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682489%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to create a snapshot of the currently running processes. Then you can use [Process32First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684834%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [Process32Next](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684836%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to enumerate through this list.

Comment: This is anm example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686701(v=vs.85).aspx Ask me if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you wanted to know how to do this on mac, this can't hurt:

```
struct ProcessList {
    pid_t value;
    struct ProcessList *next;
};

struct ProcessList *getProcesses()
{
    struct ProcessList *process = malloc(sizeof(struct ProcessList));
    struct ProcessList *next = process;
    ProcessSerialNumber psn = { 0, kNoProcess };

    GetProcessPID(&psn, &process->value);

    while (noErr == GetNextProcess(&psn)) {
        pid_t pid;
        if (noErr == GetProcessPID(&psn, &pid)) {
            next = next->next = malloc(sizeof(struct ProcessList));
            next->value = pid;
        }
    }

    next->next = NULL;
    return process;
}
```

Obviously, this returns a linked list of the processes running, until you hit NULL for a process list.

Comment: Should I include any header file? How can I print them?

Comment: @NimaAhmadi this is for Mac, And I didn't have to include any header files when compiled in Xcode.

Comment: @NimaAhmadi excuse me, after further research, it appears that it is a part of the Carbon Framework, and you must include that in your project.